# Firefox response.redirect not working for files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, firefox

I am trying to allow the user to download an excel file, by using

```
Response.Redirect(
    "http://localhost/myapp/download_folder/example excel file_july.xls")
```

in page load of an ASP.net page

but on the client side i a m getting the following screen in firefox 3.5

[image: Firefox 3.5 shows blank download screen]

You can observe that the file name and file type are shown as empty fields. The ok and cancel buttons are not doing anything.

This happens only in firefox 3.5, it is working in firefox later versions and other browsers.

I tried clearing the Response with `Response.Clear()`, using `Response.BinaryWrite` with the file byte array and even tried to open the file with the javascript by calling window.open(url).

Comment: Likely the spaces in the file name causes some issues. Try it with a filename without spaces.

Comment: @Uwe I tried without spaces(replaced spaces with _ (underscore)), it is still not working

Comment: Can you confirm that its not working on a second machine? Maybe your Firefox settings are messed up. Check out this KB from Mozilla. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Unable%20to%20download%20or%20save%20files

Comment: @Chris I checked on another machine, the problem is still there and the other thing is that if i access the file directly I am able to download it

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it the wrong way.

just as an example, look at what is done in the question body here:

[How to download file and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325770/how-to-download-file-and-reload)

in your case you should probably use an overload of `Response.Write`.

the point is that you should set some Response headers to tell the browser file name, file length and content type at least.

Comment: I tried setting the content type and Content-Disposition headers, none of them worked